Get a text from between two words
I have the following Greek Sentence which I want to process using OpenAI and get a value:
Α. ΔΥΝ. 36111 Ημερ. Εγγρ.
I tried the following prompt configuration:
The number might be located next to the phrase Α. ΔΥΝ. or before the phrase Ημερ. Εγγρ. Please return the extracted number even if it is not in a valid format. 
But I can't get the value 36111. How I can get the value?
Can I user other expresisons?

Two options here, one is to use regular expressions to programatically do this. Much faster and more performant (and cheaper). The other is to ask the model to think about a regular expression to do the job, then ask the model to use it to extract the number.

This prompt works:
Α. ΔΥΝ. 36111 Ημερ. Εγγρ.
Extract any numbers you find. Just return the numbers - no text.

This seems to work wherever the number or numbers appear in the string that you send. I checked this with gpt-4o, gpt-4, gpt-3.5-turbo, and even with Claude-3 Opus and Claude-3 Haiku.
If there are no numbers, gpt-4o returns "There are no numbers in the text you provided." If numbers are present all the above models just return the number or numbers in the phrase, with no additional text.
But if you want to be more specific about the indicator phrases, use:
Give me any number that appears close to 'Α. ΔΥΝ' or before 'Ημερ. Εγγρ.'. Just return the number. No words.

This works well with gpt-4 and gpt-4o. But not with gpt-3.5-turbo (which unaccountably returns 36110 instead of 36111).
